# is it safe to do chmod 640 /etc/passwd /etc/group?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, users, proc

I want to prevent users being able to see other system users. I've prevented listing of processes with hidepid=2 mount option to /proc, prevented listing of other users' home directories, but they can still see what users are there by doing "getent passwd" or "cat /etc/passwd".

Is "chmod 640 /etc/passwd /etc/group" safe to do? What can potentially break? Running Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139723/discussion-on-question-by-tomasz-is-it-safe-to-do-chmod-640-etc-passwd-etc-gro).

Answer (score 7):

Based on your comment:

> This is a webserver hosting many websites - and usernames/group names contain the names which allow to identify which websites are running on the server. I.e. a username can be "example.com", or "example.tld" (or similar, which allow to figure out the full domain name). Because the sites run similar software - if one site is hacked due to some vulnerability - the attacker could enumerate the sites running on the server and infect them using the same vulnerability. Hiding the ability to simply list the domains makes it harder for the attacker, and gives more time for website owners to update.

I'd say that what you want to do is provide some sort of (poor) security through obscurity.

If an attacker hacks a website, most likely they get a root shell, so 1) the whole server is compromised and 2) having gained privileged access, they can get the full list of users anyway.

On top of that, restricting permissions from system configuration files is always a bad idea. You never know what (and when) will break.

Comment: In addition, if your webserver uses `www-data` (or `apache`) the webserver must be able to see data of all users. Think about dynamic pages. So one can see all data with PHP (and BTW there are also shell that run in PHP, so restricting shell access usually is not useful). So: either you trust your users (also not overriding data, but so you should trust no vulnerability), or you must find a different way.

Comment: I disagree with "if a site gets hacked, they get a root shell". In my experience, most site exploits work because some popular software (Wordpress, Joomla, their extensions or themes etc.) have a working exploit and it actively exploited by bots. Root exploits are extremely rare (given the system is sufficiently updated). Most of the time, the attackers want to: 1) send spam, 2) add website redirects to boost their google rankings or direct people to their scammy sites - root escalation is not needed for that, and even makes their detection more probable (the server may hang etc.).

Comment: "if your webserver uses www-data" It's not. It's using php-fpm, every website has its own system account. Actually, that's more complicated. Apache DOES run as www-data, but since it can't execute anything, you can't make it read other user files (that's what's php-fpm is for).

Answer (score 4):

So far, these break:

- "ls -l" - displays uids/gids - no big deal (at least for me!)
- OpenSSH's ssh command - i.e.:

```
$ ssh user@example.com -v
No user exists for uid 1166
$ echo $?
255
```

It doesn't even attempt to establish a connection!

There is a workaround for that - using an alternative SSH client, like dropbear (dbclient):

```
$ dbclient user@example.com
dbclient: Warning: failed to identify current user. Trying anyway.
(...connection succeeds...)
```

- subversion (which uses ssh):

```
$ svn st -u
No user exists for uid 1166
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL ...
```

Workaround - editing /etc/subversion/config, [tunnels] section - and using dropbear's dbclient, not OpenSSH's ssh:

```
# ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q -o ControlMaster=no --
ssh = $SVN_SSH dbclient -q -o ControlMaster=no --
```

- other software using OpenSSH's ssh - similar workaround should help

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` both have permissions

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root
```

that means the owner = root, and the group is root.

so doing `chmod 644` on either to remove world readable ability will break the system... for whatever processes or services that are not in the root group, which they should not be (hopefully for obvious reasons), will not be able to read info out of those files regarding **uid** and **gid** probably being the two biggest ones.  The whole linux OS operates on uid and gid and what accounts have what... that is not really a security vulnerability that you need to worry about.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887247/what-are-ideal-etc-passwd-file-permissions

- **Sensitive data in modern UNIX systems is kept in /etc/shadow file.**
- what's in /etc/passwd is not *sensitive data*.

*however I think this is a good question, from a certain perspective if you have whatever reason to disallow users from being able to know all user accounts on the system from simply seeing it in `/etc/passwd`.  Then again wouldn't you also want to prevent doing an `ls -l` and gleaming user information that way?*  Is a potential solution to use LDAP where such LDAP accounts would not be present in `/etc/passwd`?*

Comment: `getent passwd` will still show LDAP accounts unless you turn enumerate off. You can also get a (partial) list of user accounts but running `ps -ef`. This is security by obscurity and a more secure method of hiding sites needs to be implemented.

Comment: Seeing other users' processes in ps output can be prevented with "hidepid=2" mount option to /proc filesystem.

Comment: How would `ls -l` or `ps -ef` help getting the _names_ associated with the UIDs? Also this answer doesn't really seem to explain what _exactly_ would break if that mapping couldn't be made. (and they did ask "_What_ can potentially break?" (emphasis mine), which seems to imply a request for specifics not just groundless fluff.)

Comment: in company/corporate work setting the employee badge number is often used as the linux UID and is also present in the account name; convenient should a username be deleted and left over files show uid instead of username for ownership; for `ls -` seeing ownership of files with `lastname_letterfirstname` lets you know **who** has accounts on your system...

Comment: what will break is any process running that is not root nor is in the root group (which should also only be root I believe).  Look at `/etc/passwd` anything having a uid and gid not matching the `/etc/passwd` (which is root)... any service type account typically having nologin as the shell... `sshd:74:74` stands out.

Comment: so the hiding of /etc/passwd is mostly security thru obscurity, and *dumbness/denial* because an `ls -l` is likely to reveal that very information... you put an extra deadbolt on your door but you have a glass window and a rock garden next to the door...

Comment: What exactly would "ls -l" reveal? As I've mentioned in the original question: "I've prevented listing of processes with hidepid=2 mount option to /proc, prevented listing of other users' home directories".

Comment: hidepid has nothing to do with the linux user name, people know you as `Tomasz` and if they see a file/folder owned by `Tomasz` via `ls -l` then um I think they just found out u have an account on that system... *I want to prevent users being able to see other system users*

Comment: hidepid=2 does what it says - hides other user's process PIDs from /proc. Other users' PIDs may include their names or have other sensitive information (it's not unknown to use passwords on command line, i.e. in mysqldump). With /etc/passwd not readable by unprivileged users - users are not able to resolve UIDs to names. In other words, "ls -l" would just show UIDs like 1234 or 2345, not names like Tomasz or Joe as you seem to suggest. And you still ignore "prevented listing of other users' home directories" - try setting chmod 751 on /home dir, then do "ls /home" as unprivileged user.

Comment: @Tomasz That's still security through obscurity, having only execute (no read) access on a directory doesn't stop anyone from enumerating its entries simply by trying all combinations (cd /home/a, cd /home/b, …, cd /home/aa, …) which can be done reasonably quickly locally

Comment: @Tomasz It is not that hard to not put passwords on the command line. In the case of `mysqldump`, I use `--defaults-extra-file=foo` to not expose the password.